# SVG element getting Cut Off

Tags: css, svg, charts, overflow, billboard.js

See this [DEMO](http://sohaibshaheen.com/price/index.php)

When hovering on the beginning or end of the X axis, the red dot that marks the position on graph, is getting cut off (either from left or right, respectively).

Any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the [clipPath](https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/release/latest/doc/Options.html#.clipPath) option.

```
bb.generate({
    ...,
    clipPath: false
});
```

EDIT:

- If you don't need to set y Axis min/max value, will work as expected
- If you need to set y Axis min/max, it need some little customization.
  Add `onafterinit` options as below, and will work as expected.

```
onafterinit: function() {
    this.mainArea.node().parentNode
        .setAttribute("clip-path",
            this.getClipPath.bind({config:{clipPath:true}})(this.clipId)
        );
}
```

Comment: It works only if Y axis start from 0, otherwise, it will mess up the part below the axis, see this [demo](http://sohaibshaheen.com/price/index_2.php), any idea?